# Question about streaming audio to mobile device (PulseAudio / AudioRelay )

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, pop-os

I can stream all audio from my pc to my android with SoundWire and it work fine, but the latency is pretty bad so i though audio relay might be a better option but i cant seem to get it working on my Pop-os pc,

With SoundWire i can select this option (Monitor for tiger lake-LP Sound Audio controller Speaker + headphones), this is the option i have to select to get SoundWire to stream System audio and not the pc's microphone

https://ibb.co/DzssGhH

But with AudioRealy I cant see this audio device as a option
https://ibb.co/jH0FxCr

Im using Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS. And latest versions of both software, is there any way to get audio relay to work